# Change location of SugarSync "Magic Briefcase" on Windows - move to root of C: drive

Tags: sync, dropbox, sugarsync

I would like to setup SugarSync on Windows similarly to how I currently have Dropbox configured, using a root sync folder located outside of any user profile - e.g., at:

```
"c:\Magic Briefcase"
```

instead of at the default:

```
"%userprofile%\My Documents\Magic Briefcase"
```

Is it possible to change the location of the Magic Briefcase in SugarSync?

With Dropbox, I make this move and then use the Windows feature of being able to move the location of the "Desktop" and "My Documents" folders to be inside the Dropbox. Then I never need to think much about where things are getting saved because it becomes a giant catch-all that works well with the defaults of nearly every application.

I know that I can link other folders so that they are within the Magic Briefcase at its default location, but I don't like having the Magic Briefcase be a subfolder of "My Documents"  since it means I would need to link all of the folders I want to backup (e.g., everything else in "My Documents") to be inside that subfolder, and always remember to save files inside that subfolder.

Any assistance much appreciated!

Comment: It seems like this is possible in Sugarsync 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the program you are using, but if there is no option to change the folder you can most likely do the following:

1. Get [NTFS-Link](http://elsdoerfer.name/ntfslink).
2. Stop the Program.
3. Move it to the location you want.
4. Create a Link to the old location and name the link "Magic Briefcase" (drag and drop with right mouse button).
5. Start the program again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I was trying to avoid using Windows symlinks - just not sure if I trust them to work reliably. Was looking for a configuration setting within the program. I found some info here that seems like it may trick the program into doing the move I am looking for: Install or move Magic Briefcase to a different hard drive? - http://sugarsync.hivelive.com/posts/e223482e86